# RPi crashes randomly after 1 to 2 days

Tags: wifi, kernel

I don't know what causes it so I write down what I found out so far, hoping it matters:

- I have multiple rpis installed in my house, all running perfectly, except this one.
- I exchanged that rpi already, also the power supply and the sd card in it. I copied the sd onto a new one, so any filesystem error etc. might still be causing it. But I have no idea.
- It is the only rpi currectly connected not by ethernet wire but by WIFI. I use a EDIMAX EW-7811UN. I already replaced that as well.
- After a reboot everything is fine, at some point /var/log/messages starts containing entries like this:

> ```
> Apr 26 17:17:12 gardeneast kernel: [160403.285169] CPU: 0 PID: 4586 Comm: kworker/0:2 Tainted: G      D W      3.18.7+ #755
> Apr 26 17:17:12 gardeneast kernel: [160403.313727] Workqueue: events od_dbs_timer
> Apr 26 17:17:12 gardeneast kernel: [160403.327924] [<c00151fc>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<c0012710>] (show_stack+0x20/0x24)
> Apr 26 17:17:12 gardeneast kernel: [160403.356381] [<c0012710>] (show_stack) from [<c0555b30>] (dump_stack+0x20/0x28)
> Apr 26 17:17:12 gardeneast kernel: [160403.374797] [<c0555b30>] (dump_stack) from [<c0039d60>] (process_one_work+0x360/0x444)
> Apr 26 17:17:12 gardeneast kernel: [160403.402947] [<c0039d60>] (process_one_work) from [<c003a998>] (worker_thread+0x190/0x580)
> Apr 26 17:17:12 gardeneast kernel: [160403.431557] [<c003a998>] (worker_thread) from [<c003edf8>] (kthread+0xd8/0xf4)
> Apr 26 17:17:12 gardeneast kernel: [160403.449926] [<c003edf8>] (kthread) from [<c000e988>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x20)
> Apr 26 17:17:12 gardeneast kernel: [160403.503255] CPU: 0 PID: 4586 Comm: kworker/0:2 Tainted: G      D W      3.18.7+ #755
> Apr 26 17:17:12 gardeneast kernel: [160403.531949] Workqueue: events BlinkWorkItemCallback [8192cu]
> Apr 26 17:17:12 gardeneast kernel: [160403.547943] [<c00151fc>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<c0012710>] (show_stack+0x20/0x24)
> Apr 26 17:17:12 gardeneast kernel: [160403.576332] [<c0012710>] (show_stack) from [<c0555b30>] (dump_stack+0x20/0x28)
> Apr 26 17:17:12 gardeneast kernel: [160403.594707] [<c0555b30>] (dump_stack) from [<c0039d60>] (process_one_work+0x360/0x444)
> Apr 26 17:17:12 gardeneast kernel: [160403.623210] [<c0039d60>] (process_one_work) from [<c003a998>] (worker_thread+0x190/0x580)
> Apr 26 17:17:12 gardeneast kernel: [160403.651869] [<c003a998>] (worker_thread) from [<c003edf8>] (kthread+0xd8/0xf4)
> Apr 26 17:17:12 gardeneast kernel: [160403.670260] [<c003edf8>] (kthread) from [<c000e988>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x20)
> Apr 26 17:17:12 gardeneast kernel: [160403.721667] CPU: 0 PID: 4586 Comm: kworker/0:2 Tainted: G      D W      3.18.7+ #755
> Apr 26 17:17:12 gardeneast kernel: [160403.750935] Workqueue: events_power_efficient fb_flashcursor
> Apr 26 17:17:12 gardeneast kernel: [160403.767903] [<c00151fc>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<c0012710>] (show_stack+0x20/0x24)
> Apr 26 17:17:12 gardeneast kernel: [160403.796472] [<c0012710>] (show_stack) from [<c0555b30>] (dump_stack+0x20/0x28)
> Apr 26 17:17:12 gardeneast kernel: [160403.815150] [<c0555b30>] (dump_stack) from [<c0039d60>] (process_one_work+0x360/0x444)
> Apr 26 17:17:12 gardeneast kernel: [160403.843399] [<c0039d60>] (process_one_work) from [<c003a998>] (worker_thread+0x190/0x580)
> Apr 26 17:17:12 gardeneast kernel: [160403.872901] [<c003a998>] (worker_thread) from [<c003edf8>] (kthread+0xd8/0xf4)
> Apr 26 17:17:12 gardeneast kernel: [160403.891996] [<c003edf8>] (kthread) from [<c000e988>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x20)
> Apr 26 17:17:12 gardeneast kernel: [160403.946287] CPU: 0 PID: 4586 Comm: kworker/0:2 Tainted: G      D W      3.18.7+ #755
> Apr 26 17:17:12 gardeneast kernel: [160403.975256] Workqueue: events BlinkWorkItemCallback [8192cu]
> Apr 26 17:17:12 gardeneast kernel: [160403.991175] [<c00151fc>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<c0012710>] (show_stack+0x20/0x24)
> Apr 26 17:17:12 gardeneast kernel: [160404.020100] [<c0012710>] (show_stack) from [<c0555b30>] (dump_stack+0x20/0x28)
> Apr 26 17:17:12 gardeneast kernel: [160404.038625] [<c0555b30>] (dump_stack) from [<c0039d60>] (process_one_work+0x360/0x444)
> Apr 26 17:17:12 gardeneast kernel: [160404.067273] [<c0039d60>] (process_one_work) from [<c003a998>] (worker_thread+0x190/0x580)
> Apr 26 17:17:12 gardeneast kernel: [160404.095978] [<c003a998>] (worker_thread) from [<c003edf8>] (kthread+0xd8/0xf4)
> Apr 26 17:17:12 gardeneast kernel: [160404.114522] [<c003edf8>] (kthread) from [<c000e988>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x20)
> Apr 26 17:17:12 gardeneast kernel: [160404.165922] CPU: 0 PID: 4586 Comm: kworker/0:2 Tainted: G      D W      3.18.7+ #755
> Apr 26 17:17:12 gardeneast kernel: [160404.194346] Workqueue: events_power_efficient fb_flashcursor
> Apr 26 17:17:12 gardeneast kernel: [160404.210311] [<c00151fc>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<c0012710>] (show_stack+0x20/0x24)
> Apr 26 17:17:12 gardeneast kernel: [160404.239152] [<c0012710>] (show_stack) from [<c0555b30>] (dump_stack+0x20/0x28)
> Apr 26 17:17:13 gardeneast kernel: [160404.257793] [<c0555b30>] (dump_stack) from [<c0039d60>] (process_one_work+0x360/0x444)
> Apr 26 17:17:13 gardeneast kernel: [160404.289065] [<c0039d60>] (process_one_work) from [<c003a998>] (worker_thread+0x190/0x580)
> Apr 26 17:17:13 gardeneast kernel: [160404.318293] [<c003a998>] (worker_thread) from [<c003edf8>] (kthread+0xd8/0xf4)
> Apr 26 17:17:13 gardeneast kernel: [160404.337813] [<c003edf8>] (kthread) from [<c000e988>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x20)
> Apr 26 17:17:13 gardeneast kernel: [160404.392035] CPU: 0 PID: 4586 Comm: kworker/0:2 Tainted: G      D W      3.18.7+ #755
> Apr 26 17:17:13 gardeneast kernel: [160404.420648] Workqueue: events od_dbs_timer
> Apr 26 17:17:13 gardeneast kernel: [160404.436581] [<c00151fc>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<c0012710>] (show_stack+0x20/0x24)
> Apr 26 17:17:13 gardeneast kernel: [160404.465130] [<c0012710>] (show_stack) from [<c0555b30>] (dump_stack+0x20/0x28)
> Apr 26 17:17:13 gardeneast kernel: [160404.483737] [<c0555b30>] (dump_stack) from [<c0039d60>] (process_one_work+0x360/0x444)
> Apr 26 17:17:13 gardeneast kernel: [160404.512941] [<c0039d60>] (process_one_work) from [<c003a998>] (worker_thread+0x190/0x580)
> Apr 26 17:17:13 gardeneast kernel: [160404.542122] [<c003a998>] (worker_thread) from [<c003edf8>] (kthread+0xd8/0xf4)
> Apr 26 17:17:13 gardeneast kernel: [160404.560879] [<c003edf8>] (kthread) from [<c000e988>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x20)
> Apr 26 17:17:13 gardeneast kernel: [160404.613283] CPU: 0 PID: 4586 Comm: kworker/0:2 Tainted: G      D W      3.18.7+ #755
> Apr 26 17:17:13 gardeneast kernel: [160404.642115] Workqueue: events_power_efficient fb_flashcursor
> Apr 26 17:17:13 gardeneast kernel: [160404.658198] [<c00151fc>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<c0012710>] (show_stack+0x20/0x24)
> Apr 26 17:17:13 gardeneast kernel: [160404.686989] [<c0012710>] (show_stack) from [<c0555b30>] (dump_stack+0x20/0x28)
> Apr 26 17:17:13 gardeneast kernel: [160404.705373] [<c0555b30>] (dump_stack) from [<c0039d60>] (process_one_work+0x360/0x444)
> Apr 26 17:17:13 gardeneast kernel: [160404.734886] [<c0039d60>] (process_one_work) from [<c003a998>] (worker_thread+0x190/0x580)
> Apr 26 17:17:13 gardeneast kernel: [160404.764513] [<c003a998>] (worker_thread) from [<c003edf8>] (kthread+0xd8/0xf4)
> Apr 26 17:17:13 gardeneast kernel: [160404.783418] [<c003edf8>] (kthread) from [<c000e988>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x20)
> Apr 26 17:17:13 gardeneast kernel: [160404.840255] CPU: 0 PID: 4586 Comm: kworker/0:2 Tainted: G      D W      3.18.7+ #755
> Apr 26 17:17:13 gardeneast kernel: [160404.869632] Workqueue: events BlinkWorkItemCallback [8192cu]
> ```

- approx. 30 minutes later, the system crashes, after a reboot I can find this entry in /var/log/message:

> ```
> Apr 26 17:17:14 gardeneast kernel: [160405.761998] CPU: 0 PID: 4586 Comm: kworker/0:2 Tainted: G      D W      3.18.7+ #755
> Apr 26 17:17:14 gardeneast kernel: [160405.793514] Workqueue: events od_dbs_timer
> Apr 26 17:17:14 gardeneast kernel: [160405.808272] [<c00151fc>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<c0012710>] (show_stack+0x20/0x24)
> Apr 26 17:17:14 gardeneast kernel: [160405.837937] [<c0012710>] (show_stack) from [<c0555b30>] (dump_stack+0x20/0x28)
> Apr 26 17:17:14 gardeneast kernel: [160405.862826] [<c0555b30>] (dump_stack) from [<c0039d60>] (process_one_work+0x360/0x444)
> Apr 26 17:17:14 gardeneast kernel: [160405.890940] [<c0039d60>] (process_one_work) from [<c003a998>] (worker_thread+0x190/0x580)
> Apr 26 17:17:14 gardeneast kernel: [160405.919735] [<c003a998>] (worker_thread) from [<c003edf8>] (kthread+0xd8/0xf4)
> Apr 26 17:17:14 gardeneast kernel: [160405.939493] [<c003edf8>] (kthread) from [<c000e988>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x20)
> Apr 26 17:17:14 gardeneast kernel: [160405.958133] ------------[ cut here ]------------
> Apr 26 17:17:14 gardeneast kernel: [160405.958201] Modules linked in: snd_bcm2835 snd_pcm snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer snd spi_bcm2708 8192cu uio_pdrv_genirq uio
> Apr 26 17:17:14 gardeneast kernel: [160405.958219] CPU: 0 PID: 4586 Comm: kworker/0:2 Tainted: G      D W      3.18.7+ #755
> Apr 26 17:17:14 gardeneast kernel: [160405.958262] Workqueue: events console_callback
> Apr 26 17:17:14 gardeneast kernel: [160405.958272] task: d92fb600 ti: d9186000 task.ti: d9186000
> Apr 26 17:17:14 gardeneast kernel: [160405.958298] PC is at gen_pool_alloc+0x23c/0x240
> Apr 26 17:17:14 gardeneast kernel: [160405.958320] LR is at __dma_alloc+0x1cc/0x27c
> Apr 26 17:17:14 gardeneast kernel: [160405.958332] pc : [<c03099cc>]    lr : [<c00199ac>]    psr: 00000013
> Apr 26 17:17:14 gardeneast kernel: [160405.958332] sp : d9187c48  ip : d9187c98  fp : d9187c94
> Apr 26 17:17:14 gardeneast kernel: [160405.958337] r10: 00000000  r9 : 00000000  r8 : d9187d2c
> Apr 26 17:17:14 gardeneast kernel: [160405.958344] r7 : 00000247  r6 : 00000000  r5 : db113440  r4 : 00100000
> Apr 26 17:17:14 gardeneast kernel: [160405.958351] r3 : 0000000c  r2 : d9187c48  r1 : 00001000  r0 : db113440
> Apr 26 17:17:14 gardeneast kernel: [160405.958360] Flags: nzcv  IRQs on  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment kernel
> Apr 26 17:17:14 gardeneast kernel: [160405.958369] Control: 00c5387d  Table: 1a318008  DAC: 00000015
> Apr 26 17:17:14 gardeneast kernel: [160405.958901] [<c03099cc>] (gen_pool_alloc) from [<c00199ac>] (__dma_alloc+0x1cc/0x27c)
> Apr 26 17:17:14 gardeneast kernel: [160405.958925] [<c00199ac>] (__dma_alloc) from [<c0019bb8>] (arm_dma_alloc+0xa4/0xb0)
> Apr 26 17:17:14 gardeneast kernel: [160405.958947] [<c0019bb8>] (arm_dma_alloc) from [<c001dd08>] (bcm_mailbox_property+0x5c/0x1f0)
> Apr 26 17:17:14 gardeneast kernel: [160405.958977] [<c001dd08>] (bcm_mailbox_property) from [<c03298c4>] (bcm2708_fb_blank+0x60/0x98)
> Apr 26 17:17:14 gardeneast kernel: [160405.959001] [<c03298c4>] (bcm2708_fb_blank) from [<c03229c4>] (fb_blank+0x64/0xb8)
> Apr 26 17:17:14 gardeneast kernel: [160405.959019] [<c03229c4>] (fb_blank) from [<c031e368>] (fbcon_blank+0x1f0/0x298)
> Apr 26 17:17:14 gardeneast kernel: [160405.959042] [<c031e368>] (fbcon_blank) from [<c0347dd0>] (do_blank_screen+0x1c4/0x27c)
> Apr 26 17:17:14 gardeneast kernel: [160405.959065] [<c0347dd0>] (do_blank_screen) from [<c034ae2c>] (console_callback+0x84/0x160)
> Apr 26 17:17:14 gardeneast kernel: [160405.959091] [<c034ae2c>] (console_callback) from [<c0039b3c>] (process_one_work+0x13c/0x444)
> Apr 26 17:17:14 gardeneast kernel: [160405.959111] [<c0039b3c>] (process_one_work) from [<c003a998>] (worker_thread+0x190/0x580)
> Apr 26 17:17:14 gardeneast kernel: [160405.959137] [<c003a998>] (worker_thread) from [<c003edf8>] (kthread+0xd8/0xf4)
> Apr 26 17:17:14 gardeneast kernel: [160405.959168] [<c003edf8>] (kthread) from [<c000e988>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x20)
> Apr 26 17:17:14 gardeneast kernel: [160405.959198] ---[ end trace 48e359ef86e63f53 ]---
> ```

- I tried with and without "options 8192cu rtw_power_mgnt=0 rtw_enusbss=0" in /etc/modprobe.d/8192cu.conf . I read it turn power safe functions off in the wifi adapter.
- During this time, network response time slows down.
- I run current updated rasbian: Linux gardeneast 3.18.7+ #755 PREEMPT Thu Feb 12 17:14:31 GMT 2015 armv6l
- I stopped all my own processes on it and just ran it doing nothing. The described effects and the crash still occurs.

Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: I believe that something in the file system is defineitly corrupt, tried connecting the raspi to your network with ethernet?

Comment: This looks like a segfault, which would indicate that you're writing something to a protected area of RAM (which could mean an area already in use, such as currently being read).  What is this RPi doing, exactly?  It might help us determine where the error is coming from.

Comment: Also possible: are you using a custom driver or module as part of this?  The 'tainted' workers would seem to indicate the RPi kernel is operating outside of "community bounds," or basically being used in a way that the kernel developer hadn't intended it to be used.

Comment: I have some self written processes running on it. But as I wrote in the last point of my problem description, the problem even occurs when all of them are not running. Just booting the rpi, let it do nothing and this happens. I load the spi module and the 8192cu module is loaded for the wifi. This line in the log BlinkWorkItemCallback [8192cu] makes me think it's somehow related to the wifi. But I ran another rpi a few months back with the same wifi connected for months without problems. That was before the device tree update though. No idea if that could cause it.

Comment: I replaced the 8192cu wifi adapter with a 8188eu and a driver from https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=462982 , exactly this version: 8188eu-20150406.tar.gz So far, it runs for 2 days and 14 h. It never worked so long with the 8192cu for me. I'll report back in a few days if it still runs.

Comment: Ok 12 more days and it still runs. I'ld guess there is something bugged with the 8192cu module at least for me.

Comment: I had a similar case. My would only crash after connecting to ethernet. I replaced it under warranty and the problem went away.

Answer (score 1):

Like you said the module is incompatible with the kernel.

Comment: But I downloaded the one matching the version number of my kernel. How can that be incompatible? And if so, where can I get a compatible one? After all it is the suggested wifi adapter for the raspberry pi.